# OkHttp3 Debugging network latency via event listeners - connectionReleased event

Tags: java, network-programming, okhttp

My Java 8 application is using OkHttp3 to make N HTTP calls to an endpoint. Consider there's some work in a queue, and some M threads are dequeueing, parsing the work and firing HTTP calls. Around 40% of the initial calls go to the endpoint, and the application gets a response. Then the application starts getting timeouts.
I enabled some logging via event listeners and got these 2 samples

#### Successful call

```
12:51:25.833 [pool-1-thread-28] INFO callStart : 76089 : time=0 for id=974745017410
12:51:25.833 [pool-1-thread-28] INFO connectionAcquired : 76177 : time=0 for id=974745017410
12:51:25.833 [pool-1-thread-28] INFO requestHeadersStart : 76178 : time=0 for id=974745017410
12:51:25.833 [pool-1-thread-28] INFO requestHeadersEnd : 76178 : time=0 for id=974745017410
12:51:25.833 [pool-1-thread-28] INFO requestBodyStart : 76178 : time=0 for id=974745017410
12:51:25.833 [pool-1-thread-28] INFO requestBodyEnd : 76178 : time=0 for id=974745017410
12:51:26.137 [pool-1-thread-28] INFO responseBodyStart : 74586 : time=304 for id=974745017410
12:51:26.137 [pool-1-thread-28] INFO responseBodyEnd : 74586 : time=0 for id=974745017410
12:51:26.137 [pool-1-thread-28] INFO connectionReleased : 76177 : time=0 for id=974745017410
12:51:26.137 [pool-1-thread-28] INFO callEnd : 74586 : time=0 for id=974745017410
```

Here we can see all the events got printed, and the network call latency was 304ms

#### Timed out call

```
12:51:16.134 [pool-1-thread-55] INFO callStart : 76088 : time=0 for id=258173443243
12:51:16.134 [pool-1-thread-55] INFO connectionAcquired : 76176 : time=0 for id=258173443243
12:51:16.134 [pool-1-thread-55] INFO requestHeadersStart : 76177 : time=0 for id=258173443243
12:51:16.134 [pool-1-thread-55] INFO requestHeadersEnd : 76177 : time=0 for id=258173443243
12:51:16.134 [pool-1-thread-55] INFO requestBodyStart : 76177 : time=0 for id=258173443243
12:51:16.134 [pool-1-thread-55] INFO requestBodyEnd : 76177 : time=0 for id=258173443243
12:51:26.134 [pool-1-thread-55] INFO connectionReleased : 76176 : time=10000 for id=258173443243
```

There isn't enough documentation on connectionReleased event, and what it denotes.

1. I am trying to understand what connectionReleased event is.
2. In the timed out call, I see the responseBodyStart and responseBodyEnd is missing.
   a. Does this denote that the server never returned a response.
   b. Are there some other events to find if the client was just overloaded to read the response from the server

I am using version 4.9.2 of OkHttp3. Consider the server as infinitely scalable. It returns a rate-limit exceeded error when it can't handle any more requests. My application is sending only 15% of requests that the server could handle

I tried setting a custom connection pool with maxIdleConnections as many as the threads as the application is using, but ran into the same problem

Comment: The docs are here https://square.github.io/okhttp/features/events/

connectionReleased doesn't say much about your request. When you request finishes, the connection will be released back to the ConnectionPool for reuse. If it is unhealthy it will also be closed.

But you should be looking for why your request failed.